# Do bond energies differ for surface and bulk atoms in nanoparticles?

Tags: surface-chemistry, nanotechnology

In nano-particles, surface atoms have fewer neighboring atoms in compare to bulk atoms.
Is there any difference between bond energy of surface atoms and bulk atoms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, as surface atoms and bulk atoms have different bond energies in nanoparticles. This is a reason why nano particles coagulate easily and special measures have to be taken to prevent coagulation.

Comment: I'd point out that nanoparticles have a lot of weird behaviors that are not typical of a bulk solid. So for atom "neighborhoods" there are (1) bulk solid (2) surface of bulk solid (3) nanoparticles